# Swift 3 multiple AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

very new to Swift, so forgive the naivety of my question.
I've built a very simple app with 3 buttons each one playing a different sound. It works fine, but the code isn't very efficient since I've created a player for each sound to be played, so I'm wondering how to use only one instance of the player to play all the sounds. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player1 = AVAudioPlayer()
    var player2 = AVAudioPlayer()
    var player3 = AVAudioPlayer()

    @IBAction func playU3(_ sender: Any) {
        player3.play()
    }

    @IBAction func playU2(_ sender: Any) {
        player2.play()
    }
    @IBAction func playU1(_ sender: Any) {
        player1.play()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let audioPath3 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound-3", ofType: "mp3")
        let audioPath2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound-2", ofType: "mp3")
        let audioPath1 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound-1", ofType: "mp3")


        do {

            try player3 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath3!))
            try player2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath2!))
            try player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath1!))


        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please check this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player : AVAudioPlayer!

    @IBAction func playU3(_ sender: Any) {
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound-3", ofType: "mp3")
        do {

            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
            player.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func playU2(_ sender: Any) {
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound-2", ofType: "mp3")
        do {

            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
            player.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func playU1(_ sender: Any) {
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound-1", ofType: "mp3")
        do {

            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
            player.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've modified it a bit so I have the 3 `audioPath` variable created at the top rather than inside every `playU1` function etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewControllerDup: UIViewController {  
var audioPlayerArray         = [AVAudioPlayer]()

@IBAction func playU3(_ sender: Any) {
   playSound("sound-3.mp3")
}

@IBAction func playU2(_ sender: Any) {
    playSound("sound-2.mp3")
}
@IBAction func playU1(_ sender: Any) {
    playSound("sound-1.mp3")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func playSound(_ soundName: String)
{

    var audioPlayer        = AVAudioPlayer()
    let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundName, ofType: nil)!)

    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound )
        audioPlayerArray.append(audioPlayer)

        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    catch{
        print("error")
    }  
}    
 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
}
```

Comment: How to pass audio url to avaudioplayer

Comment: just pass audio file name like `playSound("sound-1.mp3")`

Comment: No i have written 
        let url = Foundation.URL(string: audFile)! as URL
        
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)            
           player.prepareToPlay()
           player.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }

Comment: I want to play sound from URL http://site4brandz.com/cphp/26/uploads/KaabilHoon.mp3 But its giving Error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)